# Memcpy from a char * buffer to a wchar_t * buffer

Tags: c++

Basically I have

```
void FileReader::parseBuffer(char * buffer, int length)
{
  //start by looking for a vrsn
  //Header seek around for a vrns followed by 32 bit size descriptor
  //read 32 bits at a time
  int cursor = 0;
  char vrsn[5] = "vrsn";
  cursor = this->searchForMarker(cursor, length, vrsn, buffer);
  int32_t size = this->getObjectSizeForMarker(cursor, length, buffer);
  cursor = cursor + 8; //advance cursor past marker and size
  wchar_t *version = this->getObjectForSizeAndCursor(size, cursor, buffer);
  cout << version << "\n";
  delete[] version;
}

wchar_t* FileReader::getObjectForSizeAndCursor(int32_t size, int cursor, char *buffer) {
  wchar_t *destination = NULL;
  destination = new wchar_t[(size/2)+1];
  memcpy(destination, buffer + cursor, size);
  return destination;
}
```

in my example say i have the following bytes

7672736E - marker vrsn

00000040 - size of string to follow

0032002E0030002F00530065007200610074006F002000530063007200610074006300680020004C004900560045002000440061007400610062006100730065 - string

the string uses 16 bytes per character, so i cannot use a char * for the actual string, wchar_t seems like the best bet.

However when i memcpy these bytes to a wchar_t i get 0x7fe7abc037e0 in cout which i assume is a pointer?

which seems wrong. when i use wcout i get nothing in the terminal.

Will memcpy not work for this?

also should my wchar_t size be halved since i only have half as many wchar_t's as i would have chars?

size is a byte count.

Comment: memcpy works on bytes only, the interpretation as char or wchar is irrelevant. I'm not sure what is the "array I get back"...

Comment: i guess i don't know how to ask my question then. I want it to write 2 bytes to each item in the wchar_t but it doesnt seem to work. i can now see that the output of 0x7fe7abc037e0 is a pointer most likely. which makes sense. but i would expect, wcout to contain my entire string, rather than nothing.

Comment: memcpy doesn't do what you want. It copies byte to byte, it doesn't know that you think that the source is char and the destination is wchar. You need to write your own conversion function for that (or find an existing one, I'm sure there're plenty).

Comment: And I have no idea what "cout" you're talking about, there's no such thing in your code.

Comment: sorry its in the function that calls this. updated my question.

Comment: and does cout know how to interpret wchar_t* type? Or it casts it to a void*? Looks like it casts to void* and prints a pointer.

Comment: `cout` does *not* understand `wchar_t*`, only `wcout` does.

Comment: ok when i try wcout, i get nothing.

Comment: I need T-shirts made.. "Got gdb?"

Comment: @WhozCraig: unless it's MSVC. (though, admittedly, the VS debugger is quite nice, and in many ways preferable to GDB...)

Comment: its not, idk how to use GDB sorry :/

Comment: im just learning C++ / C. i should really learn gdb i guess.

Comment: @nneonneo I *totally* prefer the VS debugger to any other i've *ever* used, (well, maybe SoftIce back in the day...) but I assumed this was on a linux or mac box. Probably wrong of me. Most engineers will get the gdb ref even if they come from windows though. so yeah, it would make a great shirt.

Comment: yeah im on osx, ive used gdb with xcode (now lldb) and objective-c, but i am not using xcode, so im not sure how to use it on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string looks like it's in big endian order, but you are (probably) using a little-endian machine. Therefore, your `wchar_t` string is full of characters like U+3200 which your terminal might not correctly print out.

You will have to properly flip every one of those characters. Your best bet is to just treat the input as a `unsigned char *` and copy the elements one-at-a-time into your `wchar_t *` with the correct endian reversal:

```
int wlen = size/2;
uint16_t *dest = new uint16_t[wlen + 1];
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)(buffer + cursor);
for(int i=0; i<wlen; i++) {
    dest[i] = (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];
    ptr += 2;
}
dest[wlen] = 0;
return dest;
```

Note that you can't assume `wchar_t` is 16 bits wide. If you can use C++11 features, use `char16_t`.

Comment: ok yeah that was, my original idea, but someone suggested memcpy, but i don't think they had this complete context.

Comment: In his sample input, the 'size of string to follow' is 64, and the string that follows is 64 bytes long. Therefore, I guessed that the size was the size in bytes (also implied by the fact that it's a generic 'object size' and not specifically a 'string size').

Comment: But, if I'm wrong, it's a pretty simple fix (you just say `wlen = size` instead of `wlen = size/2`).

Comment: is it safe to cast dest to a wchar_t ? in this code?

Comment: if i check to see the expected size of wchar_t and make sure to padd it accordingly i can just cast the uint16 to a wchar_t?